# Python Regular Expression to get KVMs out of virsh list --all

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a Python regular expression that takes words that meet the following requirements:

1. prefix the word (**MUST be at the start of a new line**): " (number)     " (A space, a number, and then 5 spaces)
2. suffix of the word: " " (A space)

Example input:

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     VM1      running
 2     VM2      running
 3     KVM3     running
```

Output:
{VM1, VM2, KVM3}

I'm very new to Regex, and what I got so far is:

```
re.findall("(?<!\S)\S+(?!\S)")
```

Which gets me words that start and end with: " "

Comment: Show us what you have tried Please.

Comment: Good job! But this is like asking for a horse nailed to your horse shoe. Either post a more complete code, or if that's not possible, try to break your question down to smaller questions.

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex returns all of the VM names in the sample data.  It will return any name that's on a line that begins with a number.

[Here's the solution on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Kilc4d/2).  You can use Regex101.com as a playground to test out solutions.  It also give you guidance on how the regex you input is being interpreted.

The regex is `^\s+?\d+\s+([^\s]+)`

- `^` start at the beginning of the string and any subsequent line.
- `\s+?` match optional leading space
- `\d+` match any number of digits
- `\s+` match any number of spaces
- `([^\s]+)` capture an entire string delimited by space